# Fedora 32 switch root won’t start after upgrade, boots to emergency mode

Tags: fedora, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I just upgraded from Fedora 30 to Fedora 32 directly using the commands specified in the upgrading guide. Note that I used --`allowerasing`

> sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=32 --allowerasing

When I try to reboot using any of my Fedora releases (I am using a dual boot with Windows Boot Manager on a laptop), I get the following error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Switch Root.
```

When running `systemctl status initrd-switch-root.service` I get:

```
Failed to switch root: Specified switch root path '/sysroot' does not seem to be an OS tree. os-release file is missing.
```

`/sysroot` is indeed an empty folder, link to os-release is missing, but I still have `/usr/lib/os-release` with correct content, it seems.

Following some solutions I found online, I tried:

```
mkdir -p /sysroot/etc
cp /usr/lib/os-release /sysroot/etc/
reboot
```

But on reboot, I keep getting same error.
I also tried inspired on another bug report:

```
mount -o remount,rw /sysroot
cd /sysroot/usr/lib
ln -s os.release.d os-release.d   
exit
```

But the first line returns `mount point not mounted or bad option`.
When I try to manually create the symlink to `/usr/lib/os-release` and reboot, it's not there anymore and I get error again.

Any idea on how to solve this? It would be an immense help, thanks!